# Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^ {m \times n} $ has a zero null space. Show that $A$ is left invertible and $A^TA$ is positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, matrix-equations

I am stuck with the following question.:

> Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^ {m \times n} $ has a zero null space. Show that $A$ is left invertible and $A^TA$ is positive definite.

How do I show that $A$ has a left inverse without using the linear transformation perspective i.e., $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \Rightarrow \exists T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$  given by $x \mapsto Ax$.

I just want to use basic matrix theory stuffs like SVD etc. prove the existence of left inverse of $A$

Comment: Show that $A^TA x= 0$ implies $Ax=0$. What does that say about $A^TA$.

Comment: @copper.hat How can $Ax$ be $0$ if $A$ has a zero (trivial) null space unless $x = 0$ in which case we deduce nothing...?

Comment: Perhaps read what I wrote carefully?

Comment: Yes I read that...but couldn't understand. Can you explain?

Comment: Did you show that $A^TA x = 0$ implies $Ax = 0$?

Comment: @copper.hat Since, $A$ has full column rank so it means $A^{T}A$ is invertible and multiplying by $(A^TA)^{-1}$ on both sides yields $x = 0$ so $Ax = 0$ Now?

Comment: @RyukendoDey How do you know that $A$ having full column rank implies $A^TA$ is invertible? That is exactly what copper.hat is trying to lead you to

Comment: Note that $x^T (A^TA) x = \|Ax\|^2$ from which you can deduce positive definiteness of $A^TA$. For the other, try solving $Ax = y$ for $y$ by multiplying both sides by $A^T$.

Comment: For a rather overkill solution: $A^TA$ is positive definite. Eigen decomposition immediately implies invertibility

Comment: @copper.hat How do I show the existence of left inverse of $A$

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: @copper.hat
\begin{align}
Ax &= y \\
A^TAx &= A^Ty \\
x &= (A^TA)^{-1}A^T y
\end{align}
Now???

Comment: @copper.hat Don't leave me alone . Thanks for the help though dude...

Comment: Then $(A^TA)^{-1} A^T$ is the left inverse. If you pre-multiply $Ax$ by the left inverse, you get $x$.

Comment: I guess you got what you wanted...